# Cannot get Firebase Cloud Messaging to work on Edge browser on Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, microsoft-edge

So, I've made a simple piece of code:

Front end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>FCM TEST</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="token" style="padding-left: 50px"></p>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script>
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXX",
        appId: "XXXXX",
      };

      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();

      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
          .then(function (registration) {
            console.log(
              "Registration successful, scope is:",
              registration.scope
            );

            Notification.requestPermission()
              .then(function () {
                console.log("Notification Permission");
                let serviceWorkerRegistration = {
                  vapidKey:
                    "XXXXX",
                };
                if (registration) {
                  console.log("included registration");
                  serviceWorkerRegistration = {
                    ...serviceWorkerRegistration,
                    ServiceWorkerRegistration: registration,
                  };
                }

                return messaging
                  .getToken(serviceWorkerRegistration)
                  .then((token) => {
                    if (token) {
                      console.log("Token: ", token);
                      document.getElementById("token").innerHTML = token;
                    } else {
                      // Show permission request.
                      console.log(
                        "No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one."
                      );
                    }
                  });
              })
              .catch(function (reason) {
                console.error(reason);
              });

            messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
              console.log(
                "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received foreground message ",
                payload
              );
              // Customize notification here
              const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
              const notificationOptions = {
                body: payload.data.body,
                // icon: "/firebase-logo.png",
              };

              registration.showNotification(
                notificationTitle,
                notificationOptions
              );
            });
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Service worker registration failed, error:", err);
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXX",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    // icon: "/firebase-logo.png",
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

In the backend, I made a simple Node Express server where you can send the FcmToken from the FE. (Do need to copy the fcm token and paste it into Postman).

```
import { initializeApp, cert, applicationDefault } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase-admin/messaging";
import express, { json } from "express";
import "dotenv/config";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
  })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  next();
});

initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
});

app.post("/send", function (req, res) {
  const receivedTokens = req.body.fcmTokens;
  console.log("receivedToken", req.body.fcmTokens);
  const message = {
    data: {
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
    },
    tokens: receivedTokens,
  };

  getMessaging()
    .sendEachForMulticast(message)
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Successfully sent message",
        token: receivedTokens,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400);
      res.send(error);
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
});

app.get("/ping", function (req, res) {
  console.log("process env: ", process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Successfully pinged test",
    file: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

This piece of code actually works on the following test cases:

- Chrome Windows
- Edge Windows
- Chrome Android
- Chrome Mac OS
- Edge Mac OS

The only test case where it does **not** work is **Edge on Android**. The Edge version on my Android is 120.0.2210.64

Also, maybe interesting to note is that the onMessage function in Edge on Android is **not** invoked whilst everywhere else it is.

Does anyone know why? Or maybe have a solution? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you get any error messages? Maybe you can try the Canary version to see if the problem persists. In this case, if it's just not working properly in Edge with Android, then you can report the issue to the appropriate team, just open the lower right menu -> `All menu` -> `help and feedback`. Edit and send your report will be ok.